# Azure storage migration

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I really don't have experience with this, and I'm, wondering what's the best practice for doing azure storage handling properly.

So, when we upload a file to Azure storage, I'm creating an entry in our MSSQL database table that will reference that file. Because I read that azure blobs don't really have identifiers, and they are using URLs as identifiers, and we don't have something like FileId, how do we manage that when in the future we want to migrate that storage? Should we add custom metadata that will help us what that file is, or is there another approach?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but every blob definitely has a unique id (its URI). Are you storing that URI in your database? Also: what do you mean by wanting to migrate the storage in the future?

Comment: I'm not sure, currently, I still have to implement that, and I'm just not sure what to store. Because in the future, storage will change, and we will have to transfer all the files that are in the storage and keep all the references so that we can just change the connection string in the AppService and the data in the database should still be correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Every blob is uniquly identified by URL Like below***

```
https://StorageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/ContainerName/FileName.extension
```

You can add a custome column for URL's in your MSSQL Database table and update the FileURL for all the blob.

InFuture if you planning to Move the files from one storage `account/Container` to `another Storage Account/Container` your `StorageAccountName` and `BlobName`  will be change for that URL.So you only need to update the the two thing in that URL(String).

You can use .NET, AzCopy, and Azure CLI to migrate files between Azure storage accounts.You can refer this [***document***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/copy-blobs-from-command-line-and-code/) to achive the same.

You can update the URL(String) Using the below SQL query.

```
UPDATE 
    table_name
SET
    column_name = REPLACE(column_name, 'old_string','new_string')
WHERE
    condition;
```

**For more information you can refer this [***Doucment***](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-string-functions/sql-server-replace-function/)**

Comment: Even though I didn't use this solution, I think that this can be helpful to someone in the future when searching for how to solve this problem. In my solution, I went with creating unique file names and using tags to keep the original filename